# Is there a way to pass type to generic component before using it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
export const ComponentsOverrideContextProvider= <M extends Record<any, any>>({children, components}: {children: React.ReactNode, components: M}) => {
return <ComponentOverrideContext.Provider value={{ ...components }}>{children}</ComponentOverrideContext.Provider>;}
```

i have a component above which is generic and it should not be tight to a specific implementation, or order to avoid it i am doing something like

// concrete implementation

```
export const ConcreteProvider = ComponentsOverrideContextProvider;
```

and I need to somehow pass type to ComponentsOverrideContextProvider before end user uses it. Is there any way ?

user should not be doing like this
`<ConcreteProvider<Type>></ConcreateProvider>`
it should be typed before he calls this component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply specify the concrete type when doing your concrete implementation:

```
export const ConcreteProvider =
    ComponentsOverrideContextProvider<
        // Pass the concrete type
        Record<string, number>
    >;

() => (
    <ConcreteProvider components={{
        foo: 0,
        bar: "hello" // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    //  ~~~
    }}>
        Some children
    </ConcreteProvider>
)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4BhXSGpGmAeQDckopgAEyTMOSAB7wAvImIwAdGiIoYI2qskAeZNSiDNKGgE8ANHENGAfJYAUAbwC+ASgrkJkWHGr0mLWuxg6Hj4BYVENGAAFHG4hPjgZTQBZOAlVGkE6WV19CzMLa3svAAtgABtBIhozanB-DiyHAC44OxLyyvYW5HQFHowAOQhhGr82BpaU5wTLVvI4BbgiGABXKBo4TWY68a5efjjwtPloiFjhKDhuFDKVpCk7Nvln2tYAxodLOzRSiqqHTQAem2bw4wQOYXUx1O5z4lgoDko7mg8G8DDgoiUSFUMLilxkIPqgXBoTUYkkuIu2iQOU0DAENAA5mYaCsQAAjOHwyg2JwzOA2eaLLa0LE4mJ4rxjd4POxCxaLTAQCAtAAMJnlCrg7JQUBa+GKSDKZQg+DggMBcAAovxoC0ACpGMBIOAAcnpwCZrrgwCyNAg8BQdDowEZNBQ7LKLpgEDgMCdLtdrI5fFd8k1Dk+moVAGVcC6fh0qpqgZjlkhKXDyE5yEA)